# PHPMailer w/Gmail - Not Working

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I have been recently learning PHP, and I need to be able to send emails using it.

I have found out that PHPMailer is a great way to send the mail, so I have tried it out. I have set up my code according to all of the examples that I can find, but I still am unable to get it to work.

Here is my PHP code:

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);

$fc = file_get_contents("http://redxtech.ca/fbm/");

echo $fc;


if (isset($_GET["name"]) && isset($_GET["email"]) && isset($_GET["m"])) {
    $name = $_GET["name"];
    $email = $_GET["email"];
    $msg = $_GET["m"];
}
else {
    $name = "Blank Name";
    $email = "<email here>";
    $msg = "Blank";
};

$e_msg = "FB:/nYou have recieved a new submission form from " . $name . " at <" . $email . ">./n/nIt says:/n/n" . $msg . "./n/nDo what you wish with this information./n~ Gabe";


require "PHPMailerAutoload.php";

$mail = new PHPMailer;

$mail->SMTPDebug = 1;

$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = "<my gmail>";
$mail->Password = "<my super secret password>";
$mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";
$mail->Port = 587;

$mail->setFrom("<my gmail>", "Red's Mailer");
$mail->addAddress("<my other email>", "Gabe");
$mail->addAddress("<another email>", "FB");
$mail->addReplyTo("<my other email>", "Gabe");

$mail->isHTML = true;

$mail->Subject = "New Submission";
$mail->Body = $e_msg;
$mail->AltBody = "This is an altbody.";

if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo "<script>console.log('Mail was not sent')</script>";
    $errInf = $mail->ErrorInfo;
    echo "<script>console.log('Mailer Error: " . $errInf . "')</script>";
} else {
    echo "<script>console.log('Mail was sent')</script>";
}

?>
```

When I click on the submit button to send the form on the previous page, it takes me to /mail.php?name=aName&email=anEmail&m=aMsg and echo's the page, but it isn't sending the email.

When I open up Chrome Dev Tools:

"The devicemotion event is deprecated on insecure origins, and support will be removed in the future. You should consider switching your application to a secure origin, such as HTTPS. See  for more details."

However, I'm pretty sure that is caused by the embedded Vimeo players and not PHPMailer.

If anyone can give me a hand here that would be great :D

Comment: Change your debug level to 1. That should give you errors and messages.

Comment: @JasonK Where should I expect to get these error logs?

Comment: Should just send it to stdout. You may have to turn error reporting on if your not seeing anything.   error_reporting(E_ALL);

Comment: @JasonK sorry for being noob but where would I find this stdout? I am running amazon linux on an EC2 instance if that helps.

Comment: When you do a echo or a print. That is stdout. Haven't used EC2.Are you using any frameworks that maybe redirecting errors.

Comment: @RedXTech why are you printing the errors in the console? Can you simply print them in the page? Just to understand what error you are getting from PHPmailer. If you are not getting any error, you can try using `die('a message')` in the last if/else to see which branch is the code taking.

Comment: @JasonK Nope, just html, css, js, and php. And I do not know where to look for the error messages. Would it be in the console like JS's console.log?

Comment: Set SMTPDebug = 2, not 1. It will generate HTML-friendly output by default. Aside from that I suspect you're doing something very basic wrong.

Comment: @mat_jack1 I print them to the console because that's what I'm comfortable with. Also I think that I'm not even loading the PHPMailer script

Comment: @Synchro I think it might be something along the lines of not loading the PHPMailer correctly.

Comment: @RedXTech if require doesn't work you should get an error. Have you tried with the `die()` approach? What error are you getting after the `$mail->send()`?

Comment: If this script is not in the same folder as the autoloader it's probably failing at the require. Check you're using the right path to it.

Comment: you are right @Synchro. If the errors are not printed, it might be the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my own problem.

When I mentioned that I didn't think it was loading properly, that was half correct.

To fix it, I added the rest of the .php files into the same directory as the autoloader. I thought that the autoloader automatically included all of them.